# My full data is not able to display on my web page from database

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I wrote code to retrieve data from database and to print in form of tables on my web. I have stored 4 columns of data in my database but while retrieving it's only showing one column.

[My database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR18a.png)

[My webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0F3A.jpg)

My code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

        if(!$con)
       {
           die('not connected');
       }
            $result=  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, stay, food, travel,  
    SUM(stay + food + travel) AS totalamount,doj
FROM placedetails ");



?>
<div class="container">  
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>place</th>
        <th>stay cost</th>
        <th>food cost</th>
        <th>flight cost</th>
        <th>Date of journey</th>
        <th>Total cost</th>
    </tr>

</thead>



        <?php

             while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))

             {
                 ?>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stay']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['food'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['travel'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['doj'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['totalamount'] ;?></td>                
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        <?php
             }
             ?>
             </table>
            </div>
   </div>
```

Can anyone can tell where the mistake is?

And one more question: I want to diplay only the recent uploaded data on my web page. Suppose I have 4 names as mumbai, but uploaded at different times, I want to display the most recently added mumbai name on my web page

Can anyone help me out in this matter? I will be very thankful..

Comment: Move the `<tbody>` tags outside of your loop

Comment: *"i want to display the recent added mumbai name on my web page"* - ORDER BY the_date

Comment: *"but while retriving its only showing one column"* - `mysqli_fetch_array()` is the wrong function.

Comment: i have made the chnages what u have said @JohnConde then also its now showing

Comment: what should i write in the place of mysqli_fetch_array() @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your code as move tbody from php loop

```
<div class="container">  
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>place</th>
    <th>stay cost</th>
    <th>food cost</th>
    <th>flight cost</th>
    <th>Date of journey</th>
    <th>Total cost</th>
</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

    <?php

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

         {
             ?>

          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['stay']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['food'] ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['travel'] ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['doj'] ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['totalamount'] ;?></td>                
        </tr>


    <?php
         }
         ?>
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: if i want to display only the data that i have entered for the last time in database ,how my sql query should be written for that @Shafiqul Islam

Comment: only last data then 
SELECT name, stay, food, travel,  
    SUM(stay + food + travel) AS totalamount,doj
FROM placedetails order by id desc limit 1;

Answer (score 0):

1) `<tbody>` should be outside of while loop

2) if you want show only one record means no need to use `while loop`

3) if you want show recent record means just do descending sort  by `date column` or `id column`

**Query :**

```
SELECT name, stay, food, travel, SUM(stay + food + travel) AS totalamount,doj FROM placedetails order by doj desc limit 1;
```

**Table :**

```
<tbody>

<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //fetch first record set only 

?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['stay']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['food']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['travel']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['doj']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['totalamount'];?></td>                
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: But its showing the only the date that is big for ex: if i entered 12th jan for first time and 11th jan on 2nd entry...according to me it should show 11th jan but the sql query which u have designed gives me 12th jan data @JYoThI

Comment: you just use order by id column like this *SELECT name, stay, food, travel, SUM(stay + food + travel) AS totalamount,doj FROM placedetails order by  id desc limit 1;*